Partial Hamiltonian Path Optimization Problem
Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph. Define the optimization problem in which the goal is to find a subset of edges in $G$ of maximum cardinality, such that (i) the in-degree and out-degree of each vertex on this subset of edges is at most $1$, and (ii) the induced subgraph on the selected edges does not create cycles. Observe that if there is a Hamiltonian path in $G$ it is also the optimum for this problem. Thus, this problem is clearly NP-Hard. Are there known approximation-algorithms/lower bounds on approximation that can be applied to this problem? in particular, what is the best approximation we can get to this problem? Note that a 2-approximation can be obtained by finding a maximum matching.
Thank you for the help!

This can be solved exactly via a reduction to maximum matching in bipartite graphs. Given $G=(V,E)$ create a bipartite graph $H = (V_1 \uplus V_2, E_H)$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are copies of $V$. For each edge $(u,v) in E$ add edge $(u_1,v_2)$ in $H$. Matchings in $H$ correspond to edge sets in $G$ such that the in-degree and out-degree is at most $1$ so max matching $H$ is what you want.

Note that the requirement of in-degree and out-degree is at most 1 can yield cycles.

Oh I am sorry I forgot to mention that the selected edges must form an acyclic graph. I edited the question accordingly.

A more standard way of phrasing the problem might be that you want to find a pairwise vertex-disjoint set of paths, of maximum total length.
